# Rerouting traffic via NAT as a replacement for announcing IP space: what's recommended?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, nat

We were planning on using a specific VPS provider, however it turns out they don't support announcing your own IP space. Therefore, I got the idea to announce our IP space at a provider that does actually announce own IP space, and reroute all traffic from there (as an alternative to rerouting). With these means, we could reroute the traffic from our own IP space to a provider from where we would route the traffic to the VPS provider where we're not able to announce IP space.

The concept is pretty clear, and it's possible, but how would you practically set this up? (Use NAT or not? Or any better/similar alternatives?)

Comment: This question is confusing. NAT simply changes the source or destination network addresses. Routing is the process to determine, based on the destination address, out which interface the routing device should forward a received packet. I really don't understand how either of these fits into what you are describing.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sorry for the confusion. I mean routing literally, not in technical terms. Does that clear it up?